# Compare elements in two arrays and return True when one value is greater than the other using python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, for-loop, random

I'm trying to write a for loop in python that compares each ith element in one array `px` to the ith element in another array `py`. If the element in `px` is greater than or equal to that of `py` than I want to note that value as `True` or 1.

Here's some code.

```
import pandas as pd
import random

px = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=1000)
py = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=1000)

for x, y in zip(px, py):
    print("{}% {}".format(x, y))
    if px[i] >= py[i]:
       px['status'] = True
    if px[i] < py[i]:
       px['status'] = False
```

The final dataframe should look something like this:

```
px                py                status
-2.24239571e-01   -1.83834445e+00   False
1.20102447e+00    5.01755172e-03    False    
8.82060986e-02    -2.55639665e-02   True
```

I know I have some problems with my for loop.

Comment: You're defeating the point of using `numpy` by iterating through the array. Do this in a vectorized way: `x = px >= py`

Comment: Pandas support vectorized operations and the solution is as simple as df['status'] = df.px >= df.py

Comment: Please do.not.change the question like that. You took all the code out of my answer that fixed your problem and used that as a _basis_ to start a whole new question (!). That invalidated all comments and answers entirely. If this didn't solve your intended issue then you should open a new question but if this one, as originally asked, is solved then please mark accepted as appropriate.

Comment: ok, will do! didn't know. thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not be iterating through arrays if you want speed. Instead, the comparison can be done in a vectorized operation using `df['status'] = px >= py`. It's not clear from your question if the data is already in a Dataframe, so from scratch:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
px = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=1000)
py = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=1000)

df = pd.DataFrame({'px': px, 'py': py, 'status': px >= py})
print(df.head())
```

Comment: I just read your comment too. This is a much easier way to do it. Thanks so much.

Comment: hi @roganjosh your original answer was good but I realized I messed up the question and actually the answers posted do not suffice. Please try and answer if you can. You'll see the question has changed.I will still mark yours as the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

For one, the `i` you use as index is not defined.
Instead just use `x` and `y` that you already get from the for loop.