# Compare elements and return values larger than random number as true

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, for-loop, random

I'm trying to compare each unique variable in one array `px` to a random number in another array `py`. If the element in `px` is greater than or equal to that of `py` than I want to note that value as `True`.

Here's some code.

```
import pandas as pd
import random

px = np.array([0.360617,0.360617,0.360617,0.989699,0.989699,0.989699,-1.020482])
py = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=len(px))

df = pd.DataFrame({'px': px, 'py': py, 'status': px >= py})
```

The resultant dataframe looks like this:

```
         px        py  status
0  0.360617  0.509826   False
1  0.360617  0.129870    True
2  0.360617  0.818778   False
3  0.989699  0.953721    True
4  0.989699  0.740662    True
5 -1.020482  0.302593    False
```

But I need it to look something like this. Imagine that each unique `px` has its own associated random value `py` between 0 and 1.

```
name  px        py         status
a     0.360617  0.509826   False
a     0.360617  0.509826   False
a     0.360617  0.509826   False
b     0.989699  0.953721   True
b     0.989699  0.953721   True
c     -1.020482 0.302593  False
```

I imagine this can be done with a for loop where each `name` is associated with a certain random value.

Comment: You should set a seed number in your example so we all get to work with the same values for the "py" series.

Comment: How is the associated `py` determined?

Comment: @Dylan I have updated the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you need ?

```
c,n=np.unique(px,return_counts=True)
py = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=len(n))
df = pd.DataFrame({'px':  np.repeat(c,n), 'py': np.repeat(py,n), 'status': np.repeat(c,n)>= np.repeat(py,n)})


df
Out[401]: 
         px        py  status
0 -1.020482  0.862371   False
1  0.360617  0.077589    True
2  0.360617  0.077589    True
3  0.360617  0.077589    True
4  0.989699  0.376675    True
5  0.989699  0.376675    True
6  0.989699  0.376675    True
```

Comment: I beat my head against a brick wall with a groupby approach on the existing DF. Along the lines of `df['py'] = df.groupby([df.index, 'px'])['py'].first().reset_index()`. It won't work but I hoped using the index in group by would allow me to expand the result back out to all rows of `py` in the original df. Kinda like ffill based on the value of `px`. I'm sure I've seen this type of thing done simply but couldn't search it. Any idea what was needed for my approach?

Comment: Hi @Wen it worked but I did get the warning ` RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater_equal
  if __name__ == '__main__':`. I'm also curious about if you have an answer to @roganjosh

Comment: @roganjosh is this what you want ? `df.groupby(['px']).head(1).reindex(df.index).ffill()`

Comment: @JAG2024 check the previous comment  :-)

Comment: It should be `'__main__'` but that's unrelated to your question

Comment: Can't check just yet, will report back when I've tested :)

Comment: @roganjosh base n my check , previous code work well, but ffill is inefficiency  ~

Comment: @Wen yes, it won't be the most efficient. Sorry, I meant in terms of it behaving like ffill, not necessarily utilising that exact method. I think you might have answered me with `reindex` being the missing link for the approach I imagined, thanks :) I'll have another go!

Comment: @roganjosh yw：-）happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Random numbers are being generated pseudo-random way (check out [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.SystemRandom) for more information), the problem here is that everytime you call `np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=len(px))` it creates a brand new number.
In order to obtain the same pseudo-random number just use `random.seed(number)` (that number must be the same for all `py` calls, but different from the other variables) every time you want to obtain the same number as before and then call the function I mentioned above. Thus, you'll obtain the same value for `py`.

**EDIT**

Due to the comments below, I've realized (thanks to @roganjosh) another way to approach the solution is to use a `map` to store some randomly determined values for specific variables:

First of all, I've created a new map: `seeds = {"py": random.uniform(0,1)}` and whenever you want to obtain again `py` value you have to call seeds using: `seeds.get("py")` (where you can change `py` for other values). I've also created a function so you can add keys with their numerical values as much as you want:

```
def raandomseed(key):

seeds.update({key:random.uniform(0,1)})
```

For further information about pseudo-random functions check out the Python wiki [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html)

Comment: An entirely different alternative interpretation is that the OP wants to take the first `py` value for each unique `px` value and apply that to all subsequent rows where `px` has the same value.

Comment: @roganjosh In that way, you could get the first `py` value creating a random seed (and store it for future calls of `py`values), and use that `py` value to get the next `px` variable using the `random.seed(py)`.

Comment: I get the sense that the OP is less interested in the randomness and more that they could have a DF already in existence that has a variety of different values across two columns, and `random` is being used simply to generate an MCVE of what the DF looks like. The code in this question is actually mostly my code in an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48550897/4799172) question. `px` might just be fixed for convenience of the example to ensure duplicate values. It would help if the OP could clarify as several people have questions.

Comment: @roganjosh I updated the question. Is it clearer now?

Comment: @JAG2024 not for me. The debate we're having is: is your question about **(1)**  generating consistent, corresponding `py` values for each value of `px`? i.e. the problem lies in the `py = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=len(px))` code before the DF is even created or **(2)** your DF is already created and the values already exist, it has nothing to do with `random` and instead you are just trying to fix it so that `px` is always paired with the value of the first corresponding `py` value?

Comment: #2! Thank you. Sorry I didn't make that clear before.

Comment: @roganjosh but if he wants to define a constant for each variable why does he uses a random regeneration?

Comment: @JAG2024 I'm editing the question to try clarify what you're looking for because your intention is not at all clear from the question.

Comment: @JAG2024 @roganjosh and in that case, you could use a `map{key,value}`

Comment: The assigned number should be a random number between 0 and 1. What I'm really trying to do is assign a probability (between 0 and 1) for each unique value in `px`.

Comment: @JAG2024 okay, let me edit the answer with the solution.

Comment: @Jag2024 check it out now.